# How read ip address under python without resource leaks

Tags: python, ip, resource-leak

How to get the network information in Python in both Linux and Windows? I try to use netinfo package (ver 0.3.2) in Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit, but the use of this package makes the handles are not closed, as showed below. It is not accepted in my case.

```
import netinfo

def countOpenFiles():
    import resource, fcntl, os
    n_open = 0
    names = []
    soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)
    for fd in range(0, soft):
        try:
            f = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFD)
            n_open += 1
        except IOError:
            continue
    return n_open

for i in range(10):
    netinfo.get_ip('eth0')
    print countOpenFiles()
```

It produces:

```
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

I would like to have similar to netinfo package without resource leaks.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to do?
As far as I see, you don't count eth0 filehandles, but instead you count all filehandles.
If you just wan't open IP filehandles, you can use lsof (shelltool) under Linux.

lsof -u yourUser | grep IPv4
not just eth0, but I don't know how to filter that for interface.

Comment: I would like to read the ip address for wlan0 interface. This process is continuous, e.g. every second the query should be made. The netinfo.get_ip method does not release the resource (handler), as depicted in presented example. After some time (limit of 1024 handlers in python) the Python process exits with error.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I figured out that the library netifaces works well and does not leaks.